# Is it possible to make an 'int' with a decimal value in C#?

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm a new user of C#, but learned to make small simple games. So I'm having fun and training C# that way.

However, now I need to change a moving objects speed by 0.2, so I can change the speed using an interval, without the object bugging out. I'm using 'int' values to set speed  values of the objects. My objects are moving with 2 pixels per milisec (1/1000 sec). I have tried multiplying with 2, but after doing this once or twice, the objects will move so fast, they bug out.

Looked through other questions on the site, but can't find anything, which seems to help me out.

So:

Is it possible to make an 'int', which hold a decimal value ?

If yes, then how can I make it, without risking bugs in the program ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Integers are numbers without decimals, try using either the `decimal` type or `float` or `double`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You have `decimal`, `double`, etc. already.

Comment: Sure. You can scale it. Like early CPUs and signal processors did before they got floating point registers. Have to do your math much more carefully though. You can even implement your own floats.

Other than the fact you would learn a lot about floating point formats and representations, it is not clear why you would do all this unnecessary work though.

Comment: @Tim The reason I ask, is because I'm still new to this, so I only know how to use int and bool so far, but will try with float or double now, as you, and others, reffer to those :)
But thanks for the fast answer :D

Comment: @TobiasJensen - Make sure to accept Christos answer below if it helps. :)

Comment: Oh, the people equating non-integral values with `float` (and `double`)... you'd think there was no such thing as fixed-point.

Comment: See Kunth Volume 2 Chapter 4 for more information on how to represent floating point number using .... ta da.... integers :)

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to make an 'int', which hold a decimal value ?

No, a variable of type `int` can only contains an integer number. In the world of C# and CLR an `int` is any integer number that can be represented by 32 bits. Nothing less, nothing more. However, a decimal value can be represented by integers, please see update below and comments,

In your case, I think that a `float` or a `double` would do the job. (I don't refer to `decimal`, since we use `decimal` for financial calculations).

**Update**

One important outcome of the comments below, coming from [mike-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3458744/mike-wise), is the fact that a `float` could be represented by integers and actually this was the case before computers got float point registers. One more contribution on this made by mike is that we can find more information on this in the [The Art of Computer Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321751043), Volume 2 chapter 4.

Comment: This is better suited to a comment, I think.

Comment: @Tim, I think that's the only answer that can be given to this question. I will try to add some more explanation on this, but the essence is this.

Comment: Sometimes, the correct answer is just really short.

Comment: @Christos - sometimes a question can be answered in a comment :)  It's a matter of perspective and not a battle I want to get into.  You do have the essence of it.

Comment: @Tim Sure thing. I agree completely on that this is a matter of perspective. Generally, I believe, that every question that has an answer either this is small or large, should be given one in this form. Thanks

Comment: @Tim I don't see why this should be a comment. Perfectly good answer.

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate answer. Of course you can represent floats with integers. It is just a lot of work. Look at the TMS32010/

Comment: I did. People represented floats with integers all the time before computers got float point registers. I am old enough to have done it too.

I agree it does not make a lot of sense in today's environment, but it *is* possible. If you remove the that statement, I will remove the down vote.

Comment: @MikeWise The thing that I don't get is since this cannot be done in today's environment, why is that wrong. Furthermore, in the context of C#,   C and C++, the languages I have programmed most of my time, an int is a number that can be represented by 32 bits. The down vote is not my problem, but I am trying to figure out what's wrong. Is this perspective wrong? Can we assign a float in an int variable?

Comment: It *can* be done. It is just that people usually don't do it. And native ints can be 8,18,64 and 128 bits in today's environments too, not just 32. Just depends what you are programming. 
And this is rapidly deteriorating into semantics. You can't assign a float to an int (though you could in C with casting if they were the same size). But you can represent it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75663/discussion-between-christos-and-mike-wise).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only the integer part and if necessary also have a decimal , you could use a float (or double) and forcing the cast to int